# How to convert an image in pygame to a numpy array or to a number?

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

I was wondering how I can convert an image in pygame into a number. I'm making a chess game in python. I have everything made. I first made the chessboard out of string:

```
[
        ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bB", "bN", "bR"],
        ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
        ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
        ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
        ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
        ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
        ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
        ["wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wB", "wN", "wR"]]
```

I've done that for the beginning stage. I'm now working on an chess AI which can calculate fast, but if the board and images where in number form or a numpy array; it would help the calculation speed of the image like 2 or 3 times faster.

This is how I'm loading my images in:

```
IMAGES = {}
def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK', 'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
# Note we can access an image by saying "IMAGES['wp']'
```

I'm loading the images as a dictionary so that they don't bog up more cpu, plus it's cooler. As you can see the images are loaded in with their file name which is a string.

The board above is all in a string as well. The thing about my chess game I'm making is that none of the moves of the pieces require the string board at all it's just the representation of the board so I can display it on the screen. So if I could just change this board all I would have to do is just change the name of images to match them in the code. For instance: a black rook (right now: 'bR') can be changed to 01 (black) and the rook could be 012 or something. But I don't know how to do this in NumPy or python in general.

I would like people to help me. I can provide more code or any more insight you need to understand. Just tell me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way is to use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with the `return_inverse` option:

> Find the unique elements of an array.
>
> `return_inverse` *bool*, optional:  If True, also return the indices of the unique array

Example:

```py
import numpy

board = [
    ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bB", "bN", "bR"],
    ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
    ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
    ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
    ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
    ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
    ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
    ["wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wB", "wN", "wR"]
]

values, indices = numpy.unique(board, return_inverse=True)
indices = indices.reshape((8, 8))

print(values, '\n')
print(indices)
```

Output:

> ```
> ['--' 'bB' 'bK' 'bN' 'bQ' 'bR' 'bp' 'wB' 'wK' 'wN' 'wQ' 'wR' 'wp'] 
>
> [[ 5  3  1  4  2  1  3  5]
>  [ 6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6]
>  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
>  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
>  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
>  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
>  [12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12]
>  [11  9  7 10  8  7  9 11]]
> ```

Note, the values are sorted alphabetically. Hence, it does not matter how the chess pieces are arranged on the board, each piece always gets the same index, as there is at least one of each piece on the board.

---

If you want to define the values, you can just use a dictionary:

```py
lookup = {
    "--": 0,
    "wK": 1, "wQ": 2, "wR": 3, "wB": 4, "wN": 5, "wp": 6,
    "bK": 7, "bQ": 8, "bR": 9, "bB": 10, "bN": 11, "bp": 12 
}
indices = numpy.array([[lookup[p] for p in row] for row in board])

print(indices)
```

Output:

> ```
> [[ 9 11 10  8  7 10 11  9]
>  [12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12]
>  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
>  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
>  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
>  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
>  [ 6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6]
>  [ 3  5  4  2  1  4  5  3]]
> ```